# Send a message to a service bus queue with az rest

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azureservicebus

I want to send a message to a service bus with az rest, but got the error `Can't derive appropriate Azure AD resource from --url to acquire an access token. If access token is required, use --resource to specify the resource`

My code looks like this:

```
requestUri="https://${serviceBusNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/${queueName}/messages"
az rest --method post --uri "$requestUri" --body "$messagePayload"
```

Unfortunately I could not find how to specify the --resource parameter correctly to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--resource` parameter must be set to `"https://servicebus.azure.net"` for the az rest to work. The full code for a shell script would therefore look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# login to azure - may have to specify subscription
az login

# Azure Service Bus credentials
serviceBusNamespace="namespaceName"
resourceGroup="my-rg"
subscriptionId="000-111-222-333"
queueName="test"

# Get the message from the command line argument
messagePayload="Hello world!"

# Construct the request URI
requestUri="https://${serviceBusNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/${queueName}/messages"
# Send the message using az rest command
az rest --method post --uri "$requestUri" --body "$messagePayload" --resource "https://servicebus.azure.net"
```